# Modifying JWT Schemas at Runtime in .NET 8

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, bearer-token, .net-8.0

I am working on a .NET 8 project and need to dynamically modify (update, remove, add) schemas to JWT at runtime. I'm using the built-in JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core. My schemas and audiences may change and i want change this without recycling. My current code:

Appsettings

```json
{
  "AuthRules": [
    {
      "Service": "scheme1",
      "Audiences": [ "aud1", "aud2" ]
    },
    {
      "Service": "Scheme2",
      "Audiences": [ "aud1", "aud2", "aud3" ]
    }
}
```

Method for adding JWT

```
public static void AddAuthRules(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test"));

    foreach (var rule in AppConfig.getValues("AuthRules"))
    {
        List<string> audiences = new List<string>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string?> item in rule.GetSection("Audiences").AsEnumerable())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value))
                audiences.Add(item.Value);
        }

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "issExample",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudiences = audiences,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            RequireExpirationTime = false
        };

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
         .AddJwtBearer(rule.GetSection("Service").Value!, x =>
         {
             x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
             {
                 OnTokenValidated = context =>
                 {
                     // Add custom logic for token validation success
                     return Task.CompletedTask;
                 },
                 OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                 {
                     // Add custom logic for authentication failure
                     return Task.CompletedTask;
                 }
             };

             x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
             x.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is this appsetting.json is read when the application started, if you modify the appsetting.json and then we need reload the application to reload it.

Comment: I can use FileSystemWatcher for handle changes at config, but can't modify jwt config

Comment: Actually, it contains the build-in feature to monitor the appsetting.json. You are right, we couldn't modify the jwt config after the application started.

Answer (score 1):

Adding new schema requires calling `AddJwtBearer` that is called on `builder.Services`, but when `builder` already created application (using `builder.Build()`) you cannot modify services.

### Only `audencies` reloading

I got partially working solution that only reload `audencies`

```cs
var schemas = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TokenValidationParameters>();
AddAuthRules(builder, schemas);
```

Then

```cs
static void AddAuthRules(WebApplicationBuilder builder, IDictionary<string, TokenValidationParameters> schemas)
{
    var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest"));

    var auth = builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
    foreach (var rule in builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection("AuthRules").GetChildren())
    {
        List<string> audiences = new();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string?> item in rule.GetSection("Audiences").AsEnumerable())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value))
            {
                audiences.Add(item.Value);
            }
        }

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "issExample",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudiences = audiences,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            RequireExpirationTime = false
        };

        var service = rule.GetSection("Service").Value!;
        schemas.Add(service, tokenValidationParameters);
        auth.AddJwtBearer(service, x =>
         {
             x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
             {
                 OnTokenValidated = context =>
                 {
                     // Add custom logic for token validation success
                     return Task.CompletedTask;
                 },
                 OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                 {
                     // Add custom logic for authentication failure
                     return Task.CompletedTask;
                 }
             };

             x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
             x.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
         });
    }
}
```

And reloaded called before `app.Run()`

```cs
var configWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json");
configWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
configWatcher.Changed += (s, e) =>
{
    var config = new ConfigurationManager()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    var env = app.Environment;

    foreach (var rule in builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection("AuthRules").GetChildren())
    {
        var service = rule.GetSection("Service").Value!;
        if (schemas.TryGetValue(service, out var schema))
        {
            var audiences = new List<string>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string?> item in rule.GetSection("Audiences").AsEnumerable())
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value))
                {
                    audiences.Add(item.Value);
                }
            }

            schema.ValidAudiences = audiences;
        }
        else
        {
            // new schema, need restart
        }
    }
    // if something got removed also need restart
};

configWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

### Reload `app` at runtime

Other way is to recreate `builder` and `app`. I moved creating it to new method

```cs
WebApplication CreateApp(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    AddAuthRules(builder);

    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    var app = builder.Build();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();

    return app;
}
```

Then main looks like this

```cs
var isReload = false;

var app = CreateApp(args);

var configWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json");
configWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
configWatcher.Changed += (s, e) =>
{
    var oldApp = app;
    app = CreateApp(args);

    isReload = true;
    oldApp?.StopAsync();
};

configWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

do
{
    isReload = false;
    await app.RunAsync();
}
while (isReload);
```

In this case everything is reloaded, before new `app` is created old one is working, so down time is reduced to minimum, it's a single cycle of the `do..while` loop.

As this solution works it's hard to decide about memory usage or possible issues if you have `app` object globally accessible or other global singletons

---

To summarize it there are some ways to do it, but it's not supported to work this way, to reduce down time your should have replicas(combined with Load Balancer) when one is reloading other one still handling requests using old config